# Escaping quotes while calling sed from R

Tags: r, sed, quotes

When called from the terminal,

```
sed -i -e 's/^/#\x27 /' file
```

edits `file` by inserting `#'` at the beginning of each line.  But I want to do this from within `R`.  First, I note that executing the string

```
"sed -i -e \'s/^/#\x27 /\' file"
```

in `R` returns

```
"sed -i -e 's/^/#' /' file"
```

The problem is that the `\x27` got interpreted already, so my desired command

```
system("sed -i -e \'s/^/#\x27 /\' file")
```

fails with an error message about an unterminated string.  How can I pass the `sed` command to the command line from within `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what happens with that sed command on my device (a Mac). I get the same behavior using just sed as I get with doubling the backslash (i.e. escaping the backslash:

```
system("sed -i -e 's/^/#\\x27 /\' file.txt")
```

In both cases I see #\x27 in the text.

Comment: You are quite right in suggesting that I should put in the extra backslash before \x27. I even thought of trying that, but noticed that the string you fed to `system` evaluates to something unlike the original command in R, so I never even tried it!